# How to get all parents with a specific child value in asp.net mvc using LINQ?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-5

In an Asp.net MVC project I have tables(Companies,Activities and Sections), Companies can have one or many activities and each activity will have a section ("sectionId") as a foreign key to sections table. Now i want to get all companies with a specific "sectionId" (companies with activities with give sectionId).
I have used this code to get companies by name but not know how to get companies with activities has specific sections by passing the "SectionId",

```
Companies = Companies.Where(c => c.NameLatin.ToLower().Contains(NameLatin.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Comment: What can you do now and where are you stuck? Can you get the activities that contain such a section?

Comment: I can get activities with specific section but i don't know how to get companies with activities with a specific section

Comment: Can you maybe post that? We can work from there.

Comment: I have tried this

Comment: `var activites = db.Activities.Where(a => a.SectionId == SectionId);
                foreach(var activity in activites)
                {
                    Companies = Companies.Where(c => c.ApplicationUserId == activity.ApplicationUserId).ToList();
                }`

Comment: What exactly is the "ApplicationUserId"?

Answer (score 0):

It's next to impossible to guess what would work when you only post what doesn't and then without an explanation why.

Try this:

```
var sectionId = the_section_id_your_looking_for;

var applicationUserIds = db.Activities.Where(a => a.SectionId == sectionId).Select(a => a.ApplicationUserId).ToArray();

var companies = Companies.Where(c => applicationUserIds.Contains(c.ApplicationUserId)).ToList();
```

This is not ideal, because it's two statements where I'm sure you could make one out of it, but I have no idea what your structure actually looks like.